# Plotting a piece-wise function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've been trying to plot the following function along with a 45 degree line in the first quadrant in LaTeX

```
$a_{t}^{i}(k_{t}^{i})=
\begin{cases} 
      log(1+ck_{t}^{i}) & k_{t}^{i} < \widehat{k} \\
      B \frac{(k_{t}^{i})^{1-m}-1}{1-m} & k_{t}^{i} \geq \widehat{k}
   \end{cases}$
```

with numerical values for `$c$`, `$B$` and `$\widehat{k}$` but `pgfplots` doesn't recognise log as a function.

The second major concern is that I do not want numbers in the axes as the function is only defined in parameters with no given values and would like to have `$\widehat{k}$` marked as a point on the graph among several others. Is there a way to achieve this?

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ axis lines = left, xlabel = $k_{t}^{i}$, ylabel = {$a_{t}^{i}$}, ] 
\addplot[ domain=0:6.12, samples=100, color=red, ] {x}; 
\addplot [ domain=0:2, samples=100, color=blue, ] {ln(1+2*x)}; 
\addplot [ domain=2:6.12, samples=100, color=blue, ] {10*((x-0.7)^(-1.5)-1)/(-1.5)}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is true. TikZ/PGFPlots only knows `ln`, `log2` and `log10`. And since PGFPlots calculates plots with numbers, I guess you have to use some numbers for your variables/constants and then simply change the number labels to the variable/constant labels.

Comment: Thanks @StefanPinnow your advice was really helpful and i have been able to plot the log function but can't still get rid of the numbers.
My code is as follows.
Thank you.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $k_{t}^{i}$,
ylabel = {$a_{t}^{i}$},
]
\addplot[
domain=0:6.12,
samples=100,
color=red,
]
{x};
\addplot [
domain=0:2,
samples=100,
color=blue,
]
{ln(1+2*x)};
\addplot [
domain=2:6.12,
samples=100,
color=blue,
]
{10*((x-0.7)^(-1.5)-1)/(-1.5)};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

Comment: You can accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @NoelCampbell, you are welcome. As a remark: At least your code would have been better suited as an edit to your question, so it is easily copy-able (in a formatted manner). In addition: Did the answer of [Dr. Manuel Kuehner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358115/95441) help you to solve the remaining question or do you (still) need further assistance?

Answer (score 1):

> In general it is required on this site that you provide a complete code example
>   that shows your problem with the minimal required complexity, see [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

I show here how to **manually** **set** the **tick labels**.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $k_{t}^{i}$, 
    ylabel = {$a_{t}^{i}$},
    xtick = {2,4},
    xticklabels = {{Text at 2},{Text at 4}},
    ytick = {2,6},
    yticklabels = {{Text at 2},{Text at 6}},
    ] 
    \addplot[ 
        domain=0:6.12, 
        samples=100, 
        color=red
        ] {x}; 
    \addplot[ 
        domain=0:2, 
        samples=100, 
        color=blue
        ] {ln(1+2*x)}; 
    \addplot[
        domain=2:6.12, 
        samples=100, 
        color=blue
        ] {10*((x-0.7)^(-1.5)-1)/(-1.5)}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]